# Make Doctrine to return the results of the predefined order of array criteria

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I need a predefined set of results from my Doctrine repository. I am using the `findBy` method and pass my array like this:

`$this->myReposirtory->findBy(['value1', 'value2', 'value3']);`

The problem is now that Doctrine automatically orders the returned result by `id`. What I need is the exact order of the array input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extract a custom order from your database. If your parameters are, for example, [5, 4, 6], you'll get [4, 5, 6] or [6, 5, 4] depending on how you sort them. This is the default behavior of mysql.

If you want to get those three values you can separate queries or adding them a sortable value to get them in the order you want. Or maybe you can order them after the hydrate process in your code.

Comment: "Or maybe you can order them after the hydrate process in your code." Yes, unfortunately, I will end up with this :(

Comment: If you can modify your table structure, I recommend you to add a field 'custom_order_x' and put your values manually or using some custom criteria. You'll get a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how findBy method looks like:

```
/**
 * Finds entities by a set of criteria.
 *
 * @param array      $criteria
 * @param array|null $orderBy
 * @param int|null   $limit
 * @param int|null   $offset
 *
 * @return array The objects.
 */
public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
{
    $persister = $this->_em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister($this->_entityName);

    return $persister->loadAll($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);
}
```

So, the second argument is for ORDER BY.

Example query could be:

```
$this->myReposirtory->findBy([...], ['someValue' => 'ASC']);
```

Or, if you need more customization, you could write custom method in your repository.
More info: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder

Comment: Thanks, but my order is 100 % customer driven and independent from the database.

Comment: Hmmm...What do you mean by saying that your order is independent from the database?

Comment: I mean that it's not orderable by any database without user input. Because the order is made by the customer.

Comment: If the order is made by the customer, why don't you save that order in a custom field like I said before? Then you only will need to order using that field.

Comment: @Vangoso, the data comes from an API but the customer wants another order than the API delivers. He came up with that wish very late.

Comment: Then store the api results in another database and add the field like if you worked with metadata.